# I'm looking for a good book on FOL and set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, reference-request

I finally decided to really learn some axiomatic set theory, at least the basics. I've studied a bit of FOL, but a review would be nice.

In short, I'm looking for a book that focuses on $\sf ZFC$ or $\sf NBG$, and that  covers the necessary FOL topics to get into set theory.

Also, if it's a cheap book, that would be better. Thanks!

Comment: @user170039 Out of all the answers in those 4 questions, I believe only one even mentioned axiomatic set theory, which is my interest, and not so much logic, I'm only looking to review the necessary contents.

Comment: It should probably be obvious in this context, but what is FOL?  Or NBG... Etc.

Comment: @abiessu FOL is First order logic, $\sf NBG$ is Neumann Bernays Godel set theory, and $\sf ZFC$ is Zermelo Fraenkel set theory with the axiom of Choice.

Comment: Given that you are already familiar with the basics of FOL, my favorite introduction to set theory, Kunen: "An Introduction To Indepence Proofs" is an excellent starting point - and, compared to its alternatives, it's incredibly affordable. In case you want to skim through some FOL first, I'd recommend Enderton's: "An Introduction To Mathematical Logic". It's pretty expensive, but probably accessible at your local library.

Comment: @Stefan I believe you mean "A mathematical introduction to Logic" (I think you wrote the one you wrote is by Mendelson, and it's actually one of the books from which I learned axiomatic prop. logic :-p). I checked my uni's library and this one's not there, but I may find it somewhere else. I'll try to find the set theory one you mentioned, thanks!

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD You are right, sorry.